# How to clean up upon a crash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, crash, code-cleanup

I would like some clean-up activities to occur in case of crash of my program. I understand that some situations cannot be handled (a `SIGKILL` for instance) but I would like to cover as much as possible.

The [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/atexit.html#module-atexit) module was a good candidate but the docs explicitely state that

> The functions registered via this module are not called when the
>   program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python
>   fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called.

Are there functions or python features which allow to handle `sys.exit()` and unhandled exceptions program terminations? (these are the main one I am concerned with)

Comment: As stated by ForceBru the simplest method of cleaning up, is to check if a clean-up is required on program start. The easiest way of doing this is to create a file/s on disk which are deleted on successful program termination. If the file/s exist on start up, you need to clean-up.

Answer (score 1):

`SIGKILL` [cannot be handled](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGKILL), no matter what, your program is just terminated (killed violently), and you can do nothing about this.

The only thing you can do about `SIGKILL` is to look for data that needs to be cleaned up *during the next launch of your program*.

For other cases use `atexit` to handle Python's interpreter *normal* termination. If you've got some unhandled exceptions, see where they can occur and wrap these pieces of code in `try/except` blocks:

```
try:
    pass
except ValueError as e:
    pass
except:
    # catch other exceptions
    pass
```

To deal with `sys.exit` calls, you can wrap *the entire program's starting point* in a `try/except` block and catch the `SystemExit` exception:

```
try:
    # your program goes here
    # you're calling your functions from here, etc
except SystemExit:
    # do cleanup
    raise
```

Comment: This is also my understanding - this is why I stated that *I understand that some situations cannot be handled* , giving the example of `SIGKILL`. I am trying to cover the other cases mentioned in the question.